# YII Server Move. Internal Server Error. CDbException

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, frameworks

I am moving a site (that I did not build) to a new server.
I have downloaded all files, uploaded them to the new server.
DB has been downloaded, a new one created in cPanel/MySQL, old one imported.

I have opened the files in protected/config (main.php, console.php) and edited them with the new db/user/pass.

I downloaded/uploaded the Requirements folder and everything has passed.
I have checked php.ini and PDO support is enabled (sqlite, mysql)
PHP Version 5.4.45

When i visit ://serverip/~username/index.php I get:

> Internal Server Error
> include(Controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
> Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.

Any help as to why this is?

I have tried using a simplified start script, but that gives me:

> CDbException.
> The table 'video' for active record class 'Video' cannot be found in the database.

The database was exported/imported with no issues and they appear identical.

I have checked the table name in $tablename variable (in protected/model/video.php), and it is correct.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache error logs at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log while browsing the URL and it should give you the idea of whats happening exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No folder exists by that name or anything similar in the immediate server root. If I go into cPanel - Errors, it is blank. ?